# Organometallic Synthesis: Cp2Ti(I)Me from TiCl4

Tags: synthesis, organometallic-compounds

I've been working on this synthesis question for a couple days but I'm a little stuck. The question is:

> Using only $\ce{TiCl_{4}}$, $\ce{NaCp}$, $\ce{PhLi}$, $\ce{MeI}$, and $\ce{EtMgBr}$, synthesize $\ce{Cp_{2}Ti(I)Me}$. (should take 4 to 6 steps)

But it seems to me the synthesis can be done in 2 steps like so:

$\ce{TiCl_{4} + 2NaCp -> Cp_{2}TiCl_{2}}$

$\ce{Cp_{2}TiCl_{2} + MeI -> Cp_{2}Ti(I)Me}$

Which doesn't match the question's "4-6 steps" note, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You need a reductive step to go from Ti(IV) to Ti(III)

Comment: @waylander Cp2Ti(Me)I is titanium IV.

Comment: My bad, not enough coffee